# Rails server will not run - is this a mysql2 problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

Following a tutorial PRECISELY and trying to get rails server to run and getting the following error:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
    Gem.source_index called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
    NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
    Gem.source_index called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
    NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
    Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
    NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
    Gem.source_index called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:84.
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
      Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
      Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
        from /Users/EricFriedman/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to lock down your version of mysql2 if you are using Rails 3.0.x. In your Gemfile:

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.11"
```

Then run `bundle install` or `bundle update mysql2`.

*Edit*:

I notice you *are* using the 0.2.11 version of the mysql2 gem.

Looking more closely, I noticed this error:

> Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)

This may indicate that the mysql development headers/libraries are not available. Your installation the mysql2 gem should have failed when you ran `bundle install`. If so, you need to install these development libraries and then reinstall the gem.

Answer (score 2):

```
Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
```

you need mysql install on your box.

if you type `mysql` into a terminal what happens?

also

if you type `mysql --version` into a terminal what happens?

Comment: mysql

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3443
Server version: 5.5.13 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

Comment: mysql --version

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.13, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1

Comment: yeah you need the development headers for the gem to compile against it looks like, I don't know how to do that on mac ( You are using mac right?), but it shouldn't be too hard, go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and click the development release tab, and download appropriate version, as long as you install in the system default location, it should work

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Here is the original post: http://c.kat.pe/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/